# simply demostration on conditioned probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I don't find the answer of this simply problem:
how can I algebrically demonstrate that, with 3 variable A,B,C

$ \sum\limits_C P(B|C)P(C|A)=P(B|A)$ under condition that
 $P(A,B,C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)P(C)$

it seems trivial, but I miss the algebric steps....
thanks

Comment: the complete is:
P(A,B)=P(A) \sum_C P(C|A)P(B|C)=P(A)P(B|A)
with P(A,B,C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)P(C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial question was not clear. Assuming that you can factor your joint distribution as you said, you have:

$$
P(A,B,C) = P(A|C) P(B|C) P(C)
$$

Now, from the definition of marginalisation, we can write:

$$
P(A, B) = \sum_{c} P(A,B,C)
$$

Using $P(A, B) = P(B|A) P(A)$ and using Bayes rule to manipulate the RHS, we have:

$$
P(B|A) P(A) = \sum_{c}\frac{P(C|A) P(A)}{P(C)}P(B|C).P(C)
$$

We can take $P(A)$ out of the summation from the RHS as it does not depend on $C$
$$
P(B|A) P(A) = P(A) \sum_{c} P(C|A)P(B|C)
$$

And now we have your desired result by cancelling out $P(A)$ from both sides i.e.

$$
P(B|A) = \sum_{c} P(C|A)P(B|C)
$$

Comment: thank you! so, it isn't always true that \sum_C P(B|C)P(C|A)=P(B|A) as I believe.. bad intuition!sorry!

Comment: No, that only follows from that particular form of the joint distribution you mentioned. I suggest you edit your question to make it more clear.